# Update of feedback connections in brain

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neural-network

A recent paper by [Lillicrap](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13276) revisits the connection between deep learning models and brain and its biological plausibility. In their work, they show that it is possible to learn with fixed feedback connections that carry modulatory signals back to the upstream neurons.

Question: Is there evidence suggesting that feedback connections in brain may be fixed and only forward synapses are updated?

Comment: Related to: [Is back-prop biologically plausible?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16269/7001)